# I'm getting Error when install Docker on RHEL

Tags: linux, docker, containers, rhel

I'm newbie on Linux and Docker platform and trying to install Docker on RHEL by repository method as stated in Docker installation guide but when I type **sudo yum -y install docker-ee** I'm getting that output and I cannot continue to installation. I think that the previous steps performed correctly but can not go on other steps due to this output :

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# sudo yum -y install docker-ee
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos,
              : subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                     | 3.4 kB     00:00     
rhel-7-server-rpms                            | 3.5 kB     00:00     
(1/3): rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/group   |  104 B   00:00     
(2/3): rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/updatei | 280 kB   00:00     
(3/3): rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/primary | 446 kB   00:00     
No package docker-ee available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Previous steps by Docker guide :

```
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker*.repo export
export DOCKERURL="<DOCKER-EE-URL>"  
sudo -E sh -c 'echo "$DOCKERURL/rhel" > /etc/yum/vars/dockerurl'
sudo sh -c 'echo "7" > /etc/yum/vars/dockerosversion'
sudo yum install -y yum-utils \ device-mapper-persistent-data \lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
sudo -E yum-config-manager \--add-repo \"$DOCKERURL/rhel/docker-ee.repo"
sudo yum-config-manager --enable docker-ee-stable-18.03
Current step : sudo yum -y install docker-ee
```

What can be the problem ? Thank you so much

Comment: Does `yum repolist` show the Docker EE repo?

Comment: Did you put backslashes on a single line command, or were there line breaks in there too? Please update your question to include any line breaks.

Answer (score 9):

- I have been installing docker on RHEL by just enabling the rhel-7-server-extras-rpms repo:

  ```
  [root@server ~]# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms

  [root@server ~]# yum -y install docker
  ```
- Docker-EE is the entperise edition , not available in redhat repos , you will need to go to docker website , subscribe for the trial version , and then follow the instructions from there.

Answer (score 2):

The best friend always is the official Documentation, but try to start with Docker CE(Community Edition) instead of EE(Enterprise Edition) which is not suited to you as you mentioned you are new to the Technology. According to the link below: you should use this way:

```
# it will setup required pakcage
yum install -y yum-utils \
device-mapper-persistent-data \
lvm2 
# it will setup repo list for you!
sudo yum-config-manager \
--add-repo \
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
# Make sure that you have stable one always
sudo yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-edge

# And Finally install it
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

The Link is here [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce-1)

In case you want to install check the description in Docker Documentation again

[Docker EE setup documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/centos/#uninstall-old-docker-versions)